# IDA and GDB: Set breakpoint at specific statement

Tags: assembly, gdb, intel

I tried setting a breakpoint in GDB at 0x0804886A (see below picture), because I thought that was the address in hexadecimal where the instruction was stored. When tried `break 0x0804886A` I got the prompt `Function "0x0804886A" not defined. Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?`, and when I selected 'yes' it still didn't work.

How do you set a breakpoint at a specific address, like the address I but a red box around in the below picture?

[image]

Comment: have you rebased your binary on the load address on the system? If not rebase the binary in IDA on that load address and then put the bp on the rebased address.

Comment: I think you want b *0x804886a